# I need to Display Product Prices belongs to each Category and Sub Category - PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I have two mysql tables products and categories. I need to display product prices based on the category and sub category in table view. I need to have same as in given image below.. Please look at the attached image, then you can realize the structure of the table.

Get parent Categories

```
  $this->db->where('parent_id', null)->or_where('parent_id', 0);
        $q = $this->db->get('categories');
        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach (($q->result()) as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
```

```
$menus = $this->getParentCategories();
   
        $data = [];
       
        foreach($menus as $menu)
        {
            $submenu = $this->db->select('name, id')->get_where('categories',array('parent_id'=>$menu->id));
            $h = 0;
            foreach($submenu->result() as $sub) {
              $h++;
            }
            
            if($submenu) {
                $menu->submenu = $submenu->result();
                
            } else {
                $menu->submenu = [];
                
            }
            $menu->counts = $h;
            
            $products = $this->db->select('second_name, price, subcategory_id, category_id')->get_where('products',array('category_id'=>$menu->id));
                if($products) {
                    $menu->products = $products->result();
                } else {
                    $menu->products = [];
                }
            
            $data[] = $menu;
        }
        return $data;
```

```
<?php $i = 0; foreach ($categories as $menu) {  $i++;  ?>
   
        <thead>
            <tr class="primary">
                <th rowspan="2"></th>
                <th colspan="<?php echo $menu->counts?>">
                    <?php echo $menu->name; ?>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <?php if(!empty($menu->submenu)){ 
           $s = 0; foreach($menu->submenu as $submenu){ ?>
                <th style="max-width: 100px; width: 100px"><?=$submenu->name?></th>
            <?php $s++; } 
            } ?> 
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
            <?php if(!empty($menu->products)){ 
            foreach($menu->products as $pro){ ?>
            <tr>
                <th style="max-width: 100px; width: 100px"><?=$pro->second_name?></th>
                <th style="max-width: 100px; width: 100px"><?=$pro->price?></th>
            </tr>
            <?php } 
            } ?>
        </tbody>`your text`
    <?php } ?>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdkjc.png)